# Conditional expressions in Python Dictionary comprehensions

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

```
a = {"hello" : "world", "cat":"bat"}

# Trying to achieve this
# Form a new dictionary only with keys with "hello" and their values
b = {"hello" : "world"}

# This didn't work

b = dict( (key, value) if key == "hello" for (key, value) in a.items())
```

Any suggestions on how to include a conditional expression in dictionary comprehension to decide if key, value tuple should be included in the new dictionary

Comment: Is the condition always going to be in the form `key == "..."` or are you looking for a more generic solution?

Comment: `if key == "hello"` is not a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) and `dict(...)` not a dict comprehension.

Comment: `//` is not a valid python comment

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Move the `if` at the end:

```
b = dict( (key, value) for (key, value) in a.items() if key == "hello" )
```

You can even use *dict-comprehension* (`dict(...)` is not one, you are just using the `dict` factory over a generator expression):

```
b = { key: value for key, value in a.items() if key == "hello" }
```

Comment: Worked!! Thanks. But why is the syntax different for dict comprehensions compared to list comprehensions

Comment: @user462455: `dict((key, value) for ... in ... if ...)` is not a dictionary comprehension; it's a generator comprehension passed to `dict`, which has the same effect. Newer versions of Python have real dictionary comprehensions with the syntax `{key: value for ... in ... if ...}`.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> a = {"hello" : "world", "cat":"bat"}
>>> b = {"hello": a["hello"]}
>>> b
{'hello': 'world'}
```

and `dict(...)` is not dictionary comprehension.

Comment: won't this break if there is no HELLO key in the source dictionary? conditional add? No?

Comment: @SyedMauzeRehan, It will break if there's no `hello` key. You can use this: `b = {"hello": a.get('hello')}` (which will return `{'hello': None}` if there's no `hello` key). Or use `b = {"hello": a["hello"]} if 'hello' in a else {}` if you want to get `{}` in case of missing `hello`.

Comment: @SyedMauzeRehan, My point was "You don't need to iterate the dictionary to get single key-value pair."